# Prove that $U$ is open in $(\mathbb R^{ \oplus },e)$ but not open in $(\mathbb R^ \oplus,d)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Define metrics $d$ and $e$ on $ \mathbb R^{\oplus }$ as follows (where $ \mathbb R^{\oplus }$ refers to the set of non negative real numbers):

$d(a,b) = |a-b|+|~[a]-[b]~|$ where $[x]$ refers to the greatest integer function.

$e(a,b) = |a-b|+\dfrac {|~[2a]-[2b]~|}{2}$

Prove that $U=[\dfrac{1}{2},1)$ is open in $(\mathbb R^{  \oplus },e)$ but not open in $(\mathbb R^ \oplus,d)$.

**Attempt:** If we prove that $\dfrac {1}{2} $ is not a boundary point of the set $U=[\dfrac{1}{2},1)$ in $(\mathbb R^{  \oplus },e)$ but is a boundary point in $(\mathbb R^ \oplus,d)$, then we obtain the desired result.

For that, we must prove that $dist_e(\dfrac {1}{2},U^c ) > 0$ but $dist_d(\dfrac {1}{2},U^c ) = 0$ where $dist_e$ is the distance function = $\inf \{e(\dfrac{1}{2},w )~|~w \in U^c \}.$ Similarily for $d$.

$U^c = [0,\dfrac{1}{2})~ \bigcup ~[1, \infty)$.

$\forall w \in U^c: ~d(\dfrac{1}{2},w) = |\dfrac{1}{2}-w|+|~[\dfrac{1}{2}]-[w]~|=|\dfrac{1}{2}-w|+ [w] $.

For $w$ sufficiently close to $\dfrac{1}{2},$ we have $\inf d(\dfrac{1}{2},w) = 0$ which means: $U$ is not open in $d$

Similarily: $\forall w \in U^c: ~e(\dfrac{1}{2},w) = |\dfrac{1}{2}-w|+|~[1]-[w]~|=|\dfrac{1}{2}-w|+ |~1-[w]~| >0 $.

Hence, $U$ is open w.r.t $e$.

Is it Correct? Thanks!

Comment: To show $U$ is open (i.e. $U^c$ is closed) w.r.t $e$, don't you have to show that **no** point in $U$ is a "boundary point" (limit point of $U^c$)? Or is that somehow clear for all $x\in(1/2,1)$?

Comment: Also, $e(1/2,w) >0$ for all $w\in U^c$ does not guarantee that the infimum of those is positive. Better find some positive lower bound $e(1/2,w) >c$.

Comment: Also, saying "For $w$ sufficiently close to 1/2, we have inf $d(w,1/2) =0$" formally makes no sense. You want to say "inf $d(w,1/2) = 0$ *because* for $w$ sufficiently close to 1/2, say $|w-1/2|< \varepsilon<1/2$, we have $d(w,1/2) = |1/2-w| +0 <\varepsilon$".